# Finding effect of inputs on output (shapely values)

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, neural-networks, network

I've developed a neural network which takes in n inputs returning m outputs.

I want to see which inputs contribute most with each output. One idea I had is for all inputs/output combinations, lock the other inputs to some values, and vary the target input, analysing the target output. I'd then have a list of outputs (the same amount as the sample of inputs). I don't know if this is correct but I was thinking I could use the standard deviation of the outputs to measure how much this input affects the output. But then I remembered that all the other inputs are only locked to a very specific value. So I would then have to redo this whole process with every combination of other inputs. And then (again I don't know if this is right) average all of the standard deviations for an overall measure of how much this target input affects the target output

I..e. Let's say I use 1000 samples for my target input, I would have to do this for 1000^(n-1) input combinations. Essentially, this process has a complexity of s^n where s is the sample count. This seems very high, is this necessary? Also would this whole process, in general, really provide a good way of seeing which inputs affect each output?

Comment: Backprop gradients all the way to the input. High gradients = large impact on the output

Comment: @Recessive This still has to be done for every instance, as the gradients are dependent on the current instance

Comment: That's true, but it is much more efficient then your proposed method. Instead of doing each input individually, you can find the impact on the output with one pass for an input. As for finding the *overall* impact, inputs to a NN are generally seen as continuous, so it's fine to take a reasonably large sub sample of the overall set, and be relatively confident that your result is representative of the overall set.